# Unable to implement PartitionAware as put method of Hazelcast Map is getting called automatically during a cache miss

Tags: hazelcast, hazelcast-imap

We have a Write EntryProcessor, which updates the data. And the HazelcastMapConfig is configured to a MapStore. Whenever we are loading some data, if the data is not present in the map, load() method of MapStore is automatically triggered and data is populated into the map. (load() method calls database and fetches data.)

We don't have control on the partition here. I'm unable to use PartitionAware and direct the data into a partition as the put method, I guess, is called internally.

How do I put the data into a specific partition here(when using an entry processor and MapStore)?

Answer (score 0):

Hazelcast does not provide control over partitions to store specific entries or entries to be stored in a particular partition. PartitionAware is used to create data affinity so that related content of multiple maps can be stored on same partition. On your question, Hazelcast always honours the PartitionAware implementation of entry's key, no matter if the key is loaded through a direct **map.put** or a MapLoader.

Comment: Just to clarify. Should the MapStore class extend PartitionAware as well, is that what you're saying?

Comment: No, your key class should implement PartitionAware

Comment: How do I use the KeyClass with MapStore and EntryProcessor?

Comment: Check this out: http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.8.5/manual/html-single/index.html#data-affinity

Answer (score 0):

You can also read this blog on controlled partitioning in hazelcast 
https://blog.hazelcast.com/controlled-partitioning/